# How to use MVC 4 Form Posts

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, asp-classic, partial-views

I've come from a Classic ASP background and have started developing ASP.NET MVC 4 with C#.

Previously in classic ASP I would post the whole form and page to the resulting URL.  However in MVC4 I've seen other ways of just updating the partial view.

Basically at the moment on the left hand side of my page I have three different combo boxes with some data in.  I have a Submit button that when pressed, I want to search my database and return a list of results from the database to a partial view (I've already got the code working to search the database and populate a list of objects.), so that the whole page isn't refresh.

In addition, for partial views, can then handling paging.  For example my query could return 100 records, but the user only wants to display 20 per page giving 5 pages of results.  Is this possible ?

Can anybody offer any examples of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: For paging the results have a look at the WebMatrix or Telerik grids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for updating your partial view you should use an ajax call

```
$('.btnSubmit').on('click', function(){
$.ajax({
     url: "@(Url.Action("Action", "Controller"))",
     type: "POST",
     cache: false,
     async: true,
     data: { combo1: $('.Combo1').val(), combo2: $('.Combo2').val(), combo3: $('.Combo3').val() },
     success: function (result) {
         $(".Content").html(result);
     }
});
```

});

then on your view just put a div with class that matches where it will put the returned partial view.  For paging I just use a jquery plugin.  Here is a page that has some options http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/paging/  Let me know if you have any questions.